# Why did my Whirlpool electric stove/oven blow the control board?

Tags: oven, stove, board, smoke, chip

Info:
-Whirlpool electric stove/oven model: FFEH3054USE
-Bought new September 2022
Problem: Was cooking sauce on the stovetop burner and I smelled an electrical burning smell. Oven was OFF. I saw a puff of smoke from the front control panel and the LED display went blank. But the stovetop burner kept heating. All five burners are still working, but neither the oven nor the LED display and touchpad are functioning. The stove burners each have a pot/knob, but the oven is controlled by the touchpad.
Found: The control board seems to be the culprit. There is a 7-pin (8-pin dip format, like a 555 timer chip) IC that clearly overheated and burned. Part of the top is missing and you can see components inside it. The fuse on the board is NOT blown. No sign of heat/damage to anything else on the board (actually two boards piggybacked) or wires or harnesses, or the rest of the oven. Naturally :-O the oven has a one-year warranty, and I'm five months past it. Whirlpool will not help except to sell me a new board for near $400!
So, what would cause that chip to over heat (or be overpowered) to the point it burned? I'm reluctant to install a new board without first diagnosing the rest of the oven. The oven's heat elements have no signs of damage, neither the oven temp sensors, or anything else. Again, the oven was not being used when this ocurred. Also, the circuit break did not trip.

Comment: Pretty much "because it broke", unfortunately for you, out of warranty, and the manufacturer is being unhelpful. I'd be striking them off the replacement list, but essentially it's bad luck with no obvious cause.

Comment: You might check for product recalls at various sites, .g., https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/2004/cpsc-whirlpool-announce-recall-of-cooking-products , https://producthelp.whirlpool.com/FAQ/Product_Recall_Information , https://recalls.justia.com/household-and-office/ovens-stoves-ranges-microwaves/04-577/ BTW, see https://www.searspartsdirect.com/model/308tkb7mgr-001428/frigidaire-ffeh3054usa-electric-range-parts for board, ~US$300

Comment: I think your choices at this point are to replace the board (cheapest I found was around $200) and take a chance on the new board blowing, or replace the entire unit.